# JQuery, looking if text exist in Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html structure, how do I search using JQuery if the dom elements in "subscribedList" has value 97 for instance?

```
<div id="subscribedList">
  <div style="display:block;height: 30px;">
   <span class="subscribeNodeNo">98</span>
   <button class="unSubscribeNode btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Unsubscribe</button>
  </div>
  <div style="display:block;height: 30px;">
   <span class="subscribeNodeNo">97</span>
   <button class="unSubscribeNode btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Unsubscribe</button>
  </div>
  <div style="display:block;height: 30px;">
   <span class="subscribeNodeNo">96</span>
   <button class="unSubscribeNode btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Unsubscribe</button>
  </div>

  ...
  ...


</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check like this,

```
$("#subscribedList").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".subscribeNodeNo").text().trim() == "97") {
        alert("yes");
    }
});
```

You can use filter too,

```
var newList = $("#subscribedList .subscribeNodeNo").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == "97"
});
```

Or use `:contains` selector

```
if($("#subscribedList .subscribeNodeNo:contains('97')").length)
{

}
```

Comment: This the straight forward `if($("#subscribedList .subscribeNodeNo:contains('97')").length)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.subscribeNodeNo').each(function(i, v){
     if($(this).text() == '97'){
         alert('exist');
         return false;
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery(":contains(text)" ) and manipulate as needed.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("span:contains('98')" ).css("color", "#FF0000");
    });
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=MMqUNg6R3l

[.contains() docs on Jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)